# R: Boxplot names overlap with x axis

Tags: r

I have a probably very easy question but I just can't find a proper solution for it. I have the following code:

```
    data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30),15,2))
    names(data) <- c("BoxplotData1","BoxplotData2")
    boxplot(data, names = c("Box \n Plot \n Data1","Box \n Plot \n Data2"))
    axis(1, at=1:2,labels = FALSE)
```

which gives me an output as shown in the plot below. I would now like to change the position of the boxplot names so that there is no overlapping anymore. I just find ways to increase the distance between axis title and the names, but I just don't find a way to solve my issue.

Thank you for any comment!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the graphical parameters in `par`

```
par(mgp = c(3, 3,0))#mgp sets position of axis label, tick labels and axis
boxplot(data, names = c("Box \n Plot \n Data1","Box \n Plot \n Data2"))
```

If your labels are very long, you might also need to set `mar` to increase margin size.

Answer (score 2):

Do the boxplot with no names, add them using `axis` with the `line` parameter to give them some space. Use `lwd=0` to suppress redrawing of the axis lines and ticks:

```
boxplot(data,names=c("",""))
axis(1,at=1:2, c("Line1\nLine2\nLine3","Box\nPlot\nLine3"),
  line=2, lwd=0)
```